# NSComboBox set to Placeholder string display

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscombobox

I'm trying to display the placeholder string on the NSComboBox when an operation is failed. How to achieve this ? If I choose an item at index 1 and

```
 comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
```

is called. If the condition fails I want to display the placeholder string again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 deselectItemAtIndex:[ *comboBox indexOfSelectedItem]
```

I deselected the selected index on failed conditions.